# ASP.NET MVC (Form login): Validation of viewstate MAC failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Im trying to use ASP.NET login controls, in a ASP.NET MVC project and i get this error, when i click the submit button:

*Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.*

I have searched google and tried alot of solution, which worked for others including: 
  - Install .NET 3.5 SP1
  - 
  - Check if there is only 1  on the page

Unfortunaly notthing works. Do you guys have any other suggentions?

/Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new MVC Webapplication and take a look at how FormsAuthentication is done there. You can't use the Login Controls.